# Is using a cookie to store search choices a good idea?

Tags: php

I have a page where a user enters a search term, this then forwards to another page and runs a query based on this cookies contents. I was just wondering if it is good practice to do it this way? I know I can use a method="post (or get)" but I need the information to be consistent across several pages and queries.

Comment: If you are saving the user in a the database, then it would be wise to just save an array of search terms in the databse with the user id as the foreign key.

Comment: You can save it inside a cookie but notice that the user is able to manipulate the cookie and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need data on multiple pages of the same server just on server side use [Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

```
// save data
session_start();
$_SESSION['query'] = $query;

// next page, use data
session_start();
// do something with $_SESSION['query']
```

Answer (score 0):

A cookie will cause the data to persist across the user's entire session.

If they are running two searches in different windows, then they will keep overwriting each others data.

Use the query string, and copy the data into links/forms from the previous submission. (Make sure you apply suitable escaping to protect against XSS).